# sendmail error: No such file or directory

Tags: email, sendmail

I am trying to use `sendmail` out of the box using the default configuration. (I just need an MTA to deliver mail out from my application.) When I try to send a mail, I get:

> Cannot write ./dfv5T8wZmB004563 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=115): No such file or directory]

`QueueDirectory` in sendmail.cf says /var/spool/mqueue. I created that folder and gave write rights to the world, but the same error message persists. Note that t says doesn't exist and not permission denied. So what folder is it attempting to write to?

---

I discovered that my machine had sendmail installed and running only after I failed experimenting with Postfix. I purged Postfix and found that sendmail was running.

Comment: How/where are you calling sendmail and with what options/input? Could you add a minimal working example of what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: I was running from a Node.js Javascript (which was running fine via another MTA), and also testing manually by telneting to port 25 and entering the SMTP commands line by line, ie HELO ..., MAIL FROM..., RCPT: TO:...., and error came at the end.

Comment: From this article https://superuser.com/questions/710343/debian-sendmail-cannot-write, I killed the `sendmail` process.  Now I am unable to start it. `sudo service sendmail start` sort of does nothing. Reboting didn't help. How to I start sendmail?

Comment: sendmail is not a demon you "start" ... you just use it

Comment: What do you mean by it does nothing? Did you kill it or did you `sudo service sendmail stop`?

Comment: I killed it. Then `start` or `restart` doesn't seem to do anything in that I found nothing regarding sendmail from `ps`.

Comment: It's that there are different version of sendmail ... One is a server deamon you start and stop like e.g. networking. The other one ships with postfix and is a simple executed script. Since you removed postfix did you run `sudo apt-get autoremove`? Maybe the sendmail will also get removed and you can reinstall the version you want

Comment: I am now confused where the sendmail (with its files in /etc/mail) come from, whether from the original Ubuntu installation or as part of postfix. I installed postfix only today, but syslog shows sendmail activities as far back as May.

Comment: I purged sendmail*, reinstalled, and it worked fine with all the settings at default. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)